# Reload when setTimeout function finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reload window after a this custom function finishes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#order_form').dolPopupHide({});
    }, 3000);
    //window.location.reload();
});
</script>
```

Is there a way I can add the reload to the setTimeout function so it doesn't run until the timeout is over?

Comment: Did you try `window.location.reload();`? If so, how does that not meet your need?

Comment: It reload right away basically.  And the page doesn't fully load before it starts.

Comment: In this context, using document.ready is overkill.  setTimeout() already establishes that the code will run later.

Answer (score 7):

`reload` needs to be inside your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#order_form').dolPopupHide({});
        window.location.reload();
    }, 3000);

});
```

If you want to conceptually separate the work from the reload, you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        doWork();
        window.location.reload();
    }, 3000);

    function doWork() {
        $('#order_form').dolPopupHide({});
    }

});
```

Or, to be even more general:

```
function reloadAfterExec(fn) 
    return function() {
        fn();
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout( reloadAfterExec(function() {
        $('#order_form').dolPopupHide({});
    }), 3000);

});
```